# QlikSense set analysis with 2 conditions on the same dimensions

Tags: qliksense

My need is to display the numbers of customers who returned an order in a month "M" and placed a new order on the next 6 months after the month "M". And that has to be displayed in a bar chart in QlikSense.

I created a first measure with :
**count(distinct [Account id])**

then I added my condition on my order returned :
**count(distinct ${<[Transactions Type] = {"RETURN"}>} [Account id])**

So with that I get the numbers of customers who returned an order by month M ("Order Creation YearMonth").

I created a second measure with :
**count(distinct [Account id])**

then I added my condition on my order on the next 6 months :
**Rangesum(above(count(distinct ${<[Transactions Type] = {"ORDER"}>} [Account id]), 0, 6))**

So with that I get the numbers of customers who placed an order on the 6 next months after the month M ("Order Creation YearMonth").

In abscissa, I put my dimension "Order Creation YearMonth".

My problem is that I don't know how to merge these 2 measures in a set analyzis.

Do I have to use the p operator ?
Or the * operator to combine the 2 conditions on the "Transactions Type" ? But how can I add the rangesum ? Or maybe it is the wrong way ...

Thanks to any of you who can give me some tips to move forward on this crazy problem, my brain thanks you ! :)